# Составьте программу, печатающую строку: «ABBCDD…ZZ»

Tags: python

```
s=''
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
    s+=2*chr(i)
print(s)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ответ должен получится «ABBCDD…ZZ». А если оставить код в таком виде, то выведется "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ"

Comment: Все равно так получится, я уже пробовал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в range второй параметр должен быть больше, чем последнее значение которое вы хотите получить. в данном случае можно прибавить единицу. А чтобы чередовались 1/2 символа можно использовать остаток от деления индекса на 2

```
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
   s += ((i+1)%2 + 1)*chr(i)
print(s)   #  ABBCDDEFFGHHIJJKLLMNNOPPQRRSTTUVVWXXYZZ
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за подсказку.

Answer (score 3):

```
s=''
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
    if i % 2 == ord('A') % 2:
        s+=chr(i)
    else:
        s += 2 * chr(i)
print(s)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 3):

добавляем второй символ если код символа четный:

```
s=''

for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1):
    s += chr(i) + chr(i) * (i%2==0)  # (i%2==0) возвращает 1 если истина, 0 если ложь

print(s)  # ABBCDDEFFGHHIJJKLLMNNOPPQRRSTTUVVWXXYZZ
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```py
s = ''.join(chr(i) + 2 * chr(i+1) for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z'), 2))
# ABBCDDEFFGHHIJJKLLMNNOPPQRRSTTUVVWXXYZZ
```

или так

```py
s = ''.join(map(lambda i: chr(i) + 2 * chr(i+1), range(ord('A'), ord('Z'), 2)))
```

Можно задействовать итератор:

```py
import string
it = iter(string.ascii_uppercase)
s = ''.join(i + 2 * j for i, j in zip(it, it))
print(s)
```

Comment: с итератором ловко придумано!